MariaDB: Writing even 25MB of data into a LONGBLOB is very slow
We recently added MariaDB as a storage option for our tool. Before that we only allowed sqlite. Among other tables I have a very simple temporary file storage table:
create table tmp_file_storage
(
    uuid          varchar(255) not null,
    creation_date datetime     not null,
    filename      varchar(255) null,
    data_type     varchar(255) null,
    file          longblob     null
)

In production, writing a single entry into this table with a 25MB file (even if the table is empty), takes about 8 minutes. On my development PC it takes about 2 minutes, which is already way too slow for such a small file.
Writing the data currently happens in 2 steps:
INSERT INTO tmp_file_storage(uuid, creation_date, filename, data_type, file)
VALUES ('someuuid', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss', NULL, NULL, NULL);

UPDATE TABLE tmp_file_storage
SET
  filename='filename',
  data_type='xml',
  file='.... 25MB of data ...';
WHERE
  tmp_file_storage.uuid = 'someuuid'

First we thought it could be something about our code, but we were able to reproduce this problem with just sending those queries to MariaDB. I tried using different Storage Engines (InnoDB, MyISAM, Aria) and it always took pretty much the same time.
Here is the my.ini in case that matters. We haven't changed a lot of stuff.
[mysqld]
datadir=D:/.../data
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_log_file_size     = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size   = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 1G
max_allowed_packet       = 500M

The database runs on the same server, and doesn't have a lot of load. Maybe around 10-100 requests a minute.
With 25MB already taking so long, something seems to be actively slowing MariaDB down. In sqlite this operation usually takes less than a second. Any ideas?

What version of MariaDB is this? Where is the performance bottleneck (CPU, disk IO)?

I tested this locally with MariaDB 11.4 using this test Python program and the UPDATE took about 0.35 seconds on my system when the database was on an in-memory filesystem. When the datadir was on an NVME disk, it took 0.56 seconds. MariaDB 10.11 and 10.6 both had nearly the same performance so the versions do not seem to matter. Is the disk your database on a HDD or something else that's slow?

Things to consider:

Compress such text in the client, then store into a LONGBLOB.  (XML typically compresses 3:1.)
Store such bulky things in the filesystem, not the table.
How much RAM do you have?  Is swapping occurring?

